# How this smal infrared work

Tags: ir

I have a code that sends 384 pulses at 38kHz with an infrared LED. It's very easy to understand it. At the beggining the code sends the pulses using the LED and in the middle of the code I check the sensor if it has any signal coming. So far so good, yes? Please, take a look:

```
for(int i=0;i<384;i++) {
  digitalWrite(IRledPin,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(13);
  digitalWrite(IRledPin,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(13);
}

if (digitalRead(IRsensorPin) == LOW){
  digitalWrite(D13ledPin,HIGH);
} else {
  digitalWrite(D13ledPin,LOW);
}
```

My question is this: I first send the pulses, so when I reach the line `if (digitalRead(IRsensorPin) == LOW){` the pulse should already have passed the sensor. So why does it work? It should not work cause I first send the pulse and then I check for the pulse but as I understand the 384 pulses should already have passed the sensor.

I have no idea why this code works. I would be glad to listen smarter people to help me understand this.

Thank you.

Comment: What does the hardware look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IR receiver does some filtering on the signal. It doesn't signal a LOW immediately if it lost a single pulse of light. A speck of dust, hanging in the air, might just be blocking the IR phototransitor. Or some brief flash of light, making two pulses seem like one or more.

These IR receivers a specifically build to filter out the 'noise' coming from other light sources and light obstructions.

Identically, you would want this receiver to give you a HIGH if it detect only 2 pulses of light 13uS apart. I could just be some sunlight reflected from a puddle, accidentally matching 38kHz.

Comment: Just a final question: if I send pulses of 38kHz for 10 seconds (in the for loop) and I try to read those pulses in the next line, how many pulses I will be able to read? Just the 5 last ones? 100 last pulses? What I dont understand is this: if I send all the pulses in the for loop, when the compiler reaches the digitalRead the pulses should already be gone and nothing should be registered as HIGH. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The ir receiver doesn't return a HIGH if it detects IR light. It only returns HIGH if it detects a 38kHz signal. It will remain HIGH for as long as the 38kHz signal is present.

Comment: thanks. But you agree with me that when the arduino stops processing the for loop it alredy sent all the pulses right? So when arduino process the next lines like digitalRead it should return nothing cause the pulses already passed it. Right? I have no idea why this code works :(

Comment: In an ideal word, it should indeed not work. But in reality the ir receiver isn't sure the signal has stopped, or if it just missed a single light pulse. So it waits a little longer, before returning a LOW.